# cloudd: Tons of downstream - why?

Tags: network, icloud

Using the iStat Menus app, I can see (some) network activity connected to certain applications. Some, because Google Chrome, for instance, does never appear in the list of apps.

Since I had forgotten my internet gateway that I usually use in my dorm (a construct of a Raspberry Pi and an Airport Extreme plus a wifi dongle) back at home, but had the dongle with me, I plugged that in my mac and connected. And while this is a dongle, it has an LED that flashes on activity. On my Pi, the activity LED is re-routed to a GPIO LED - but for the time being, it sits next to the side of my macbook.

So at some point I noticed that it was blinking a lot, and all that I was running was `ssh` and Atom, plus some local daemons like MySQL and PHP-FPM. So I went to see what iStat Menu had to say, and it reported:

```
cloudd        755 kb/s
```

... Where is that coming from?

I did a google search to see if it was possible to observe iCloud activity on my Mac, but it didn't turn up anything useful.

So: How do I know what `cloudd` is doing, that requires so much downstream?And that came out of nowhere too. I haven't touched my phone the entire day, except for a call or two.